# How to ignore line break after reading two ints with cin?

Tags: c++, cin

I am new to C++, I have practically started it today. Any way, I am facing a problem where the first line contains two integers, and the next lines contain operations to be done. It's a fairly weird problem, actually, so I won't go into the details. Well, I am having a problem with reading the first line, and then the follow up operations.

My code looks like this so far:

```
int m, j;
string comando;
string OPR
cin << m << l;

while (getline(cin, comando)) {
     OPR = comando.substr(0, 3);
}
```

The problem is: Apparently, whenever I write both m and l in the same line, the \n stays in the buffer, and it get's read by the newline, causing a problem when I try to take the substring. I tried adding a char variable that would be read after m and l, which would, supposedly, get the \n. However, it is getting the first letter of the newline instead, which, then, messes up my code. I tried to see if I had any syntax errors or anything, but that isn't it. I also looked for ways to ignore the \n char, but everything I found was related to strings, or reading from files.

I know I could read the line, and then cast the two ints from string to int, but that seems like a bad way to do it (at least it would be a bad way to do it in C).

Anyways, if any one can help me, that would be awesome, thanks!

P.S.: I don't do a check before the substr operation because, by the definition of the problem, the line will have a 3-char operation, a space and then an integer.

Comment: If the second line is guaranteed to be a string followed by an integer, why not just do `cin << s << i`.

Comment: Because I want it to stop reading once it reaches the EOF, and I didn't know that I could do that simply by using cin. I looked for it online and the solution I found was the one I am using, so I assumed it was the best/only way to do it.

Comment: I actually found a solution to my problem by adding the sanity check that sees if the line input has length greater than 0. That way I don't get an error, and nothing happens until the next iteration of the while loop. Still, I'd like to know how to ignore a \n before actually needing to read a line. I understand I can use `getline` right after my cin, from @BaummiAugen's response - it also helped me to understand what was happening to my code - but is that the preferred way, or is there a 'more correct' way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good place to look for tips for common problems like this is your favorite reference:

> When used immediately after whitespace-delimited input, e.g. after `int n; std::cin >> n;`, `getline` consumes the endline character left on the input stream by `operator>>`, and returns immediately. A common solution is to ignore all leftover characters on the line of input with `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` before switching to line-oriented input.

From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).